# The data I uploaded to the Firestore database is not updated. So I can only see the data I created first

Tags: android, database, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

**This is my main page. I am getting values from user on this page**

```
 private lateinit var binding : ActivitySignInCalculatorBinding
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore



override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivitySignInCalculatorBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    auth = Firebase.auth
    db = Firebase.firestore




}

fun calculateButton(view:View){
    val postMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
    postMap.put("Panel Boyutu", binding.panelWidth.text.toString())
    postMap.put("Panel Sayisi", binding.panelCount.text.toString())



    db.collection("values").add(postMap).addOnSuccessListener {
        finish()
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this@SignInCalculator,it.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    val intent = Intent(this@SignInCalculator,DataPage::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}
}
```

**And this page is the page that the user comes to when clicking the button with the calcuteButton function. Here I show the user entered data in a textView**

```
 private lateinit var binding: ActivityDataPageBinding
private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var firestore: FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var valuesArrayList : ArrayList<Values>
private lateinit var dataAdapter : DataAdapter

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDataPageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    auth = Firebase.auth
    firestore = Firebase.firestore

    valuesArrayList = ArrayList<Values>()
    getData()

    binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    dataAdapter = DataAdapter(valuesArrayList)
    binding.recyclerView.adapter = dataAdapter



}

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "NotifyDataSetChanged")
private fun getData(){
    firestore.collection("values").addSnapshotListener { value, error ->
        if (error != null){

            Toast.makeText(this,error.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }else{
            if (value!= null){
                if (!value.isEmpty){
                    val documents = value.documents
                    for (document in documents){

                        val panelBoyutu = document.get("Panel Boyutu") as String
                        val panelSayisi = document.get("Panel Sayisi") as String


                        val values = Values(panelSayisi,panelBoyutu)
                        valuesArrayList.add(values)

                    }
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**And finally my RecyclerView Page.**

```
class DataAdapter(val valuesArrayList: ArrayList<Values>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.CalculateHolder>(){
class CalculateHolder(val binding: RecyclerRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CalculateHolder {
    val binding = RecyclerRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
    return CalculateHolder(binding)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CalculateHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.binding.panelText.text = valuesArrayList.get(position).panelSayisi
    holder.binding.panelSizeText.text = valuesArrayList.get(position).panelBoyutu


}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return valuesArrayList.size
}
```

**The problem is, as I mentioned in the title, the data filled in by a new user while completing the registration process is not updated. For example, user x registered by assigning the values 321, and user y by assigning the value 123. Whichever data is stored first on the DataPage is displayed. But it also shows the data of the 2nd user registered with 123 data in Firestore Database. It just doesn't update. How can I fix?**

Comment: IS the onFailure triggered?

Comment: No it's not triggered

Comment: Is your onSuccess triggered?